# can't remove a record from a table

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jpa

Inside my ControllerServlet class, for a doPost method, I have an action to remove a person from a db table:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String path = request.getServletPath();
        ...
        else if (path.equals("/remove_person")) {
            String id = request.getParameter("id");

            Person person = em.find(Person.class, Integer.parseInt(id));
            try {
                utx.begin();
                em.remove(person);
                utx.commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        String url = path + ".jsp";
        request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
}
```

However, when I refresh a table, a record I tried to remove still exists in the persons table. By the way, I didn't have any problems when I had to add a new person.

Below is a code of the entity Person class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "persons")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Person.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Person p"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Person.findById", query = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE v.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Person.findByName", query = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE v.name = :name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Person.findByYearBirth", query = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE v.yearBirth= :yearBirth"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Person.findByNameYearBirth", 
            query = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.name = :name or p.yearBirth = :yearBirth"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Person.deleteById", query = "DELETE FROM Person p WHERE p.id = :id")})
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "yearBirth")
    private Short yearBirth;

    // constructors, setters, getters...
}
```

So, what is a cause of this problem?

**UPDATE:**

1) I can successfully (manually) remove a record from a table or by entering an sql statement from a mysql workbranch.

2) For a following code, if I remove try/catch I get exception `java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - unreported exception javax.transaction.NotSupportedException; must be caught or declared to be thrown`

```
        Person person = em.find(Person.class, Integer.parseInt(id));
        try {
            utx.begin();
            em.remove(person);
            utx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

3) I have tried with code below to remove a record from a table but in this case I'm getting exception:

```
    javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: 
Exception Description: No externally managed transaction is currently active for this thread

Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Person.deleteById");
query.setParameter("id", Integer.parseInt(id));
query.executeUpdate();
```

ControllerServlet class

```
@WebServlet(
    name = "ControllerServlet", 
    loadOnStartup = 1,
    urlPatterns = {
        "/index", 
        "/search_person", 
        "/add_person",
        "/remove_person"})
public class ControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;
    @Resource
    private UserTransaction utx;
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        assert emf != null;
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String path = request.getServletPath();

        if (path.equals("/index")) {
        }
        else if (path.equals("/search_person")) {
            List persons = em.createNamedQuery("Person.findAll").getResultList();
            request.setAttribute("findByNameAndYearBirth", persons);
        }
        else if (path.equals("/add_person")) {
        }
        else if (path.equals("/remove_person")) {
            List persons = em.createNamedQuery("Person.findAll").getResultList();
            request.setAttribute("findAll", persons);
        }
        String url = path + ".jsp";
        request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String path = request.getServletPath();

        if (path.equals("/index")) {
        }
        else if (path.equals("/search_person")) {
            String name = request.getParameter("name");
            String yearBirth = request.getParameter("yearBirth");

            Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Person.findAll");
            if (!name.isEmpty() && !yearBirth.isEmpty()) {
                query = em.createNamedQuery("Person.findByNameAndYearBirth");
                query.setParameter("name", name);
                query.setParameter("yearBirth", Short.parseShort(yearBirth));
            }
            else if (!name.isEmpty()) {
                query = em.createNamedQuery("Person.findByModel");
                query.setParameter("name", name);
            }
            else if (!yearBirth.isEmpty()) {
                try  {
                    Short sYearBirth = Short.parseShort(yearBirth);
                    query = em.createNamedQuery("Person.findByYearBirth");
                    query.setParameter("yearBirth", sYearBirth);
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {}
            }
            List persons = query.getResultList();
            request.setAttribute("findByNameAndYearBirth", persons);
        }
        else if (path.equals("/add_person")) {
            String name = request.getParameter("name");
            String hobby = request.getParameter("hobby");
            String yearBirth = request.getParameter("yearBirth");

            int personsLen = em.createNamedQuery("Person.findAll").getResultList().size();
            Person newPerson = new Person(
                ++personsLen, name, hobby, Short.parseShort(yearBirth)
            );
            try {
                utx.begin();
                em = emf.createEntityManager();
                em.persist(newPerson);
                utx.commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        else if (path.equals("/remove_person")) {
            String id = request.getParameter("id");

            Person person = null;
            try {
                utx.begin();
                person = em.find(Person.class, Integer.parseInt(id));
                em.remove(person);
                utx.commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } 
        }
        String url = path + ".jsp";
        request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="DB_PERSON_TEST_PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/db_person_test</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

stacktrace:

```
SEVERE:   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: null is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.remove(EntityManagerImpl.java:560)
    at server.ControllerServlet.doPost(ControllerServlet.java:122)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Have you checked the logs for an exception stack trace? Why do you catch the exception in the first place? Let it bubble. Remove the try/catch.

Comment: You must be getting an exception. Don't try to run code if it doesn't compile. Replace `e.printStackTrace()` by `throw new RuntimeException(e)`.

Comment: Still no exception thrown even with a statement you told me to replace with. Check my post, I update it with a full code of the ControllerServlet class, so you can see what's going on...

Comment: Put the call to em.find() inside the transaction, not outside. And post the persistence.xml file.

Comment: I updated post with persistence.xml, I also moved em.find inside try/catch line before em.remove, still no result.

Comment: If you don't get an exception, all I can imagine is that the remove code isn't actually executed (run it using a debugger, or add traces in the code to be sure it's actually executed), or that you don't look into the correct database.

Comment: I have find out with a debugger (by the way I'm using netbeans IDE), when I hover over a statement em.remove(): "VM: Object null is not a known entity type", so now it throws an java.lang.IllegalArgumentException in my console and on the page. Ok so this is a null pointer exception, which means entity manager can not find entity I tried to remove, right ? But how this object can be null, when I can normally print this object values and see the values in the console?

Comment: So do you have any idea what should I do, now that I'm getting this java.lang.IllegalArgumentException ?

Comment: You said it yourself: you're trying to remove an object that doesn't exist. Check that it isn't null before trying to delete it.

Comment: But if it's null, then what is wrong with my code? Where is the error ?

Comment: Nothing is wrong. You're just sending the ID of an entity to remove to your servlet, and this entity doesn't exist in the table. Try sending it the ID of an entity that exists.

Comment: I even manually tried to put the ID = 1 "person = em.find(Person.class, Integer.parseInt(1));", didn't want to remove. So frustrating..

Comment: Try loading the object first, print it to see if its loaded and then remove it.

Comment: Try to be precise with your description. What does "didn't want to remove" means? Does em.find() return something? What does remove do? Does it throw an exception? Which stack trace? Does committing the transaction throw an exception? Which stack trace?

Comment: @KevinRave Just after "person= em.find(Person.class, Integer.parseInt(id));" i can use that object and System.out.println(person.toString() or person.getId()) it will print the id number... but when I  try to em.remove(person), after I print, it throws exception.

Comment: @JBNizet I'll update a stacktrace in a moment

Comment: Check if the db user has proper permissions... Just additional check.

Comment: Did you really try printing the person object after you load it (after em.find())? Don't assume, but please try.

Comment: Also, try one more thing... Put em.find() with in the transaction as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59820/discussion-between-xerath-and-kevin-rave).

Comment: Person person = null;
            try {
                utx.begin();
                person = em.find(Person.class, Integer.parseInt(id));
                em.remove(person);
                utx.commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } Doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The removal of entries from a table may be blocked by the SQL server instance itself.
You might want to double check any keys and or constraints that link the entry you want to remove to other entries.

Try manually removing the entry from the table using SQL instead of scripts, if the SQL server is indeed refusing to remove the entry because of the earlier mentioned constraints it should display an error indicating that one or more constraints are preventing you from doing so.

A workaround would be to temporarily drop all constraints, remove the entry and then reapply them.

I Hope this was informative enough to help.

Comment: I will update my post, in a few mins, something new I have tried, plus your suggestion.